# vba increment date when hour is zero

Tags: excel, vba, date, time

I've tried to look arround on google and here in StackOverflow but I can't seem to glue the code together for my purpose.
I'm using 2 columns. The first one to enter a date (dd-mm-yyyy) the second one to enter time (00:00:00). I've already found how to increment the time each 15 minutes but now I have the problem that my date only may change when the time is on 00:00:00. So for this the code needs to look in column B for this time.
So for my time I have this:

```
Sub AutomateTimeSeries
    range("B5").Select        
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C + ""00:15"""                
    Selection.AutoFill
    Destination:=range("B5:B2980"), Type:=xlFillDefault    -   
    range("A4").Select  
End Sub
```

So now I need to go look in column B for "00:00:00". If I find this in cell e.g. B98 I need to jump on A98 and change the date into previous +1. for that I need already to have a date in the previous cells. the user will fill in a date in the first presented cell. From there on the macro will fill up all the cells in column A with this date. I've used this part of the macro:

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=range("A4:A2980"), Type:=xlFillCopy
```

This works but I need to change the cell in that particular A-cell next to B-cell containing 00:00:00. How could I do this please? Or is there a better way to use Date-Time increasing.

To go left from the found cell I've tried to use:

```
Sub IncreaseDate()

    Dim a_lastrow As Integer     'last row of column A
    Dim b_lastrow As Integer     'last row of column B
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        a_lastrow = .Range("A3000").End(xlUp).Row
        b_lastrow = .Range("B3000").End(xlUp).Row

        For r = 1 To a_lastrow
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("B1:B" & b_lastrow), .Range("B" & r).Value) = "00:00:00" Then
                .Range("A" & r).Value = "previous date + 1 day"  '<==what's the code for this??????
            End If
        Next r
    End With

    MsgBox ("done")

    If (Target.Column = 2) Then    'check if in 2nd column
        If Target.Offset(, -1).Value = "" Then    'Check if there is already a value in Column A
            Target.Offset(, -1).Value = Date     ' No value, lets stick in the current system date
        End If
    End If

    SAS DateLiteral
    DateAdd


End Sub
```

So it should look like something like this:

```
1/01/2017   23:15:00
1/01/2017   23:30:00
1/01/2017   23:45:00
2/01/2017   0:00:00
2/01/2017   0:15:00
2/01/2017   0:30:00
2/01/2017   0:45:00....
```

Does anybody has an idea please?

Comment: You could use just formula.  In cell A1 enter:  `28/11/2017  00:00:00` in cell A2 enter:  `=SUM(A1,"00:15")`.  In Cell B1 enter `=A1`.  Now just give column A a custom format of `d/mm/yyyy` and column B a custom format of `hh:mm:ss`.  As you drag the formula down the date will change when you reach midnight.

Comment: Hi Darren, thank you for your quick answer. This could be a solution but in my case I need to continue for 30-31 days. and I want to do that with a single click on a button so that anyone else non vba users can use this  ;-)

Comment: I'll add as an answer with some VBA code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments - this can be done with just a formula and number formatting (the code below just adds the formula and number formatting).

Using your first piece of code as a template this will auto fill between B5:C2980.
Just add the first required date in cell B4 and the formula in B5 will calculate 15 minutes later.

Also note - there's no selecting cells.  You just work with that cell - no need to select it first.

```
Sub AutomateTimeSeries()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With .Range("B5")
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-1]C,""00:15"")"
            .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
        End With
        With .Range("C5")
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
            .NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
        End With

        .Range("B5:C5").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("B5:C2980")

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Darren, thank you for your time and code. But the code automatically fills in a date starting from 00/01/1900. The date should start at whatever the user is filling in in cell A4. So if the user fills in 01/01/2017 the date should go on from there.....

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "column A every 24 hours".  If you enter 01/01/2017 in cell B4 then the table you added at the bottom of your post appears in the range B193:C199. If you want the dates in columns A:B then the column ranges in my code will just need adjusting from B:C to A:B.

Comment: Oh crap! I'm so sorry Darren, your code is sublime! Thanks. I saw what I did wrong. I needed to clean my sheet first :-(. Sorry! thanks again, but I don't quite understand which part of the code automatically fills up the date? is it in ".NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy" "?

Comment: Cell `B4` holds the first date.  `=SUM(R[-1]C,""00:15"")"` adds 15 minutes to the previous date.  Column C holds exactly the same value as column B, the only difference being that column B is formatted to show just the date and column C is formatted to show just the time.  The bit that fills the date is just the `.Range("B5:C5").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("B5:C2980")` - as the cells holds a date and time the date will automatically change when you add 15 mins to 23:45 as you drag the formula down.

Comment: Feel free to tick it as the accepted answer if it works for you. :)